# Fix distorted mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg

In our university sometimes the recordings of videos are very distorted.

Example frame (please ignore the red bar it's just there for privacy reasons):

[image: Example Frame]

I know that basically I would need to move each pixel of each frame horizontally based on its vertical position. Is there a way to do this with FFmpeg?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the geq filter

Comment: Thanks Gyan, this seems good. But sadly I see that when the position would be outside the frame, it just uses the edge. Is there a way to set it to repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gyan, I was able to fix it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "geq=p(mod(X+Y*2\,W)\, Y)" output.mp4
```